# Error using decimals only on one system. Java

Tags: java

**Solved, there's a difference in punctuation between the two systems. I was using . in drJava for both OSX and windows. I had to use , in windows for the code to work. I assume you can change this through some setting.

I have tested the code on my mac (drjava) and it's working just fine. However, when I try the code on windows (drjava) I get a different result, and only if I use decimal numbers.

This is my code:

```
Scanner tastatur = new Scanner(System.in);  

System.out.print("Skriv in tempraturen du vil kovertere fra fahrenheit til celcius: ");  //ber brukeren taste inn en temperatur
double tall = tastatur.nextDouble(); //brukeren taster inn en temperatur

double celcius = ((tall - 32)/1.8); //konverterer grader fahrenheit til celcius

System.out.println("Temperaturen i celcius " + celcius);
```

This is my error:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
    at FahrenheitCelciusUtvidet.main(FahrenheitCelciusUtvidet.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Why do I get this error only on my windows computer?

Comment: why there is javascript tag, if you think java & javascript are same you are wrong, there is a huge difference between both.

Comment: What are your inputs?

Comment: it's work fine on my computer

Comment: You probably have different decimal points (`,` or `.`) on your windows computer and mac. Check your locale settings.

Comment: What exactly do you type in ?

Comment: I used the recommended tags. I'll edit the post. Keppil: I'll see if that works.

Comment: i'm windows and not get any error?which input give you an error?

Comment: Keppil: That worked, thanks! I wouldn't have thought there would be a difference in notation between the two systems.

Comment: From javadoc: An instance of this class is capable of scanning numbers in the standard formats as well as in the formats of the scanner's locale. A scanner's initial locale is the value returned by the Locale.getDefault() method; it may be changed via the useLocale(java.util.Locale) method. The reset() method will reset the value of the scanner's locale to the initial locale regardless of whether it was previously changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can arise if you have different locales on your two machines. Some use `,` as decimal separator, and some use `.`.

Which one is used can for example be checked via the [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) class.